# Multiple assignments in the where clause of a spock test?

Tags: groovy, spock

I'm using the Spock framework for testing, and I have a question regarding multivaraible assignment in a where clause.

I have the following test case:

```
def "sending a message delegates to message sender"() {
  when:
    sendMessage(x,y)
  then:
    1 * messageSender.send(x,y)
  where:
    x << 1
    y << 2
}
```

I want to replace the multiple variable assignments in the where clause with a single assignment operation. I tried:

```
where:
  [x,y] << [1,2]
```

but got a *MissingMethod* exception. I assume this is because the expression *[1,2]* is treated as an array rather than a list.

Note that the following worked:

```
where:
  [x,y] << [1,2].combinations()
```

It seems that the *combinations()* method returns a *List* type, but despite that the following did not work:

```
where:
  [x,y] << [1,2].asList()
```

Using *combinations()* is counter-intuitive, so I am wondering if there is a simple, elegant way of initializing multiple variables in Spock.

edit: I am using spock version 0.7-groovy-2.0

Comment: The multiple assignment syntax is `(x,y) = [1,2]` does that work

Comment: Actually, I just had a look at the docs, and for Spock it looks like `[x,y] = [1,2]` should work instead

Comment: Thanks for the comment. `(x,y) = [1,2]` generates the error *where-blocks may only contain parameterizations*, and `[x,y] = [1,2]` generates the error *ListExpression is a bad expression as the LHS of an assignment operator*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiple assignment has to be done as mentioned below:

```
[x, y] << [[1,2]]
```

Here is a [contrived example](http://meetspock.appspot.com/script/5649050225344512) where test fails for one combination.

[Multiple variable data pipes](http://spock-framework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/data_driven_testing.html#multi-variable-data-pipes) uses an example from SQL ResultSet which is pretty much similar to the above example.

Comment: Using `[x,y] << [[1,2]]` worked. I assume (from the SQL example) that the `where:` block is expecting to assign values multiple times to each variable, hence a list of tuples is required, rather than a tuple.