# Declare multiple variables in one line in Spock when: block

Tags: groovy, spock

I would like to know how I can define, without initializing, multiple variables in one line in Spock spec as shown below.

I have tried:

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class exampleSpec extends Specification {

  def "foo"() {
    when:
    def a, b
    a = 0
    b = 1

    then:
    a != b
  }
}
```

But this fails when accessing b:
`No such property: b for class: ....`

I have managed to get the following to work:
`def (a, b) = []`

But I'd like something better.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I am using:

```
Groovy Version: 2.4.3 JVM: 1.8.0_45 Vendor: Oracle Corporation OS: Linux
```

Comment: `def a, b` should work. Can you add a simple failing example to the question as well?

Comment: Also add the version of Groovy you are working with.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @dmahapatro . I just updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fear that cannot be done in any of the blocks (like `given:`, `setup:`, `when:`). There is an easy work around.

```
@Grab(group='org.spockframework', module='spock-core', version='0.7-groovy-2.0')

import spock.lang.Specification

class ExampleSpec extends Specification {

  def "foo"() {
        def a, b

        when:
        a = 0
        b = 1

        then:
        a != b
    }
}
```

Move the declaration out of `when:`/`given:`/`setup:` block and have them as method variables. The `setup:`/`given:` label is optional and may be omitted, resulting in an implicit setup block.

Although this works, I would like to know the reason why this did not work otherwise. You can create an [issue in github](https://github.com/spockframework/spock).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the where: block to pass parameters.  There's no def required because they're passed as an argument, if you're feeling fancy you can even have a test that is run multiple times.

```
    def "Use where to pass test data"(){
        expect: 1 == myNumber
                2 == myOther1
        where: myNumber = 1
               myOther1 = 2
    }
```

Here's [a link](https://github.com/ScientificMethod/SpockExamples/blob/master/SpockExamples/src/test/Parameterizations.groovy) to some other examples I've written that show how to pass data to your tests.  If you *really* like multiple assignment ([even though it's not a good idea](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2133373&seqNum=2)) [here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22160165/mutliple-assignment-in-the-where-clause-of-a-spock-test) you could use it in a where: block.

If you're curious about the various blocks here is [a summary](https://github.com/ScientificMethod/SpockExamples/wiki/Feature#parameterize) of everything I've read.  Don't take my word for it, here's [some official](http://spockframework.github.io/spock/docs/1.0/spock_primer.html) documentation.

You might be happy to know that this issue has been [raised already](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/426), but it hasn't seen any activity in the last month.  My assumption is that something about multiple assignment doesn't agree with the AST transformations that Spock uses on your code.